# What is the dot (.) in an Nftables rule

Tags: nftables

In many nftables examples, I sometimes see statement like this:

```
map nat-udp-services {
        type ipv4_addr . inet_service : verdict
    }
```

and this:

```
ip daddr . udp dport vmap @nat-udp-services
```

What does the dot (.) mean in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation

There's some more details about it [in the wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Concatenations)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you so much. I had spent all day searching for all sorts of terms. Never crossed my mind to look for concatenation.

Comment: yea understandable , a 'dot' doesn't make for much of a search term :)